# About Beginner Harmonica

Tags: harmonica

Which harmonica is best for beginners if I want to play Bollywood songs because I heard that 10 hole C-type harmonica can't play all songs?

Comment: Is your goal to become a harmonica player or do you just want to produce something that resembles a certain song as quickly as possible? The answer to your question might depend on how much work you're prepared to put in.

Answer (score 1):

A *diatonic* harp will only play songs with diatonic notes - apart from bending some to find some chromatics. *Chromatic* harps will be able to play not only diatonic songs, but also those with chromatic (out of key) notes.

Whatever you get will be designated to a particular key, although it's possible to play in *any* key on a chromonica - once you're good enough.

So, maybe consider a set of harps (10 hole) in various common keys, which you'll be able to use standard (in the key marked), or *cross-harp*, as in a key a 5th away from the key everyone else plays in - just like Blues players do.

The C-type harp you mention will essentially play tunes in key C, and key G used as a cross harp. So if, for example, there's a song in, say, key D, it won't be much use. C is the most common key found in harps though, and playing alone, won't cause too many problems.

Comment: Are 10 hole diatonics suitable to play Bollywood music? I don't know much about the genre, but if a song is based on something other than a standard major or a Dorian scale it might be hard to play well, and having several keys only helps partially.